# Texture unwrap does not appear as expected

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to unwrap a cube. I know that it is very obviously. I mark the seam and so but the texture does not appears as mentioned in the image 
[image]

Comment: you need to enable textured solid in properties tab and add a texture node in your material with that texture

Comment: @Denis, I enable it but it  does not work.

Comment: Textured solid works in blender internal, for cycles you need to add a texture node with that texture in your material and switch to textured viewport shading

Comment: @Denis, That is what I think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the texture in 3D View in **Cycles**, Texture Node should be created in the material and viewport switched to **Textured Viewport Shading**

[image]